# Comparing the role of fathers in different species

Tags: ethology, sexual-reproduction

In species where the male of the species is involved with the life of his offspring in what species is the role he takes is the same as the role of the mother, and in which species is it overlapping or distinct?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal) estimates there are 2.16 million described animal species and 7.77 million total. So, it seems an answer to your question is going to be quite long. Can you narrow/focus it a bit more?

Comment: Maybe [take a quick look at wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paternal_care) to start answering your question.

Answer (score 2):

There was a magnificent book that looked at the role of females in several primate species.  it's not new.  the title is "[The Woman that never Evolved](https://www.hup.harvard.edu/catalog.php?isbn=9780674955394)" The Author, Sarah Hrdy decided to compare the gender roles of various near relatives to imagine how human societies could have been different.  [Hrdy also wrote another book on Motherhood](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0679442650).  I'm sure there are many books on fatherhood but I like starting here for a couple of reasons.

By comparing these diverse primate societies she turned on its head previous generations of primatology that had imagined all near relatives live like humans do with a male hierarchy dictating social structure.  not only did she expand our concept of primate social structures, but she also made a statement that human society could be different.  Which, since then it has changed.

There are many diverse studies looking at male roles in primates but this is a good place to start to look at the roles of males.  Its a good comparative structure.  if you are interested in broader sorts of structures, there are so many species and different families you could start... you would have to pick one i'd think.

Comment: thanks so much! i'll get those books

Comment: This does seem useful to the OP, but I'm failing to see how it answers the actual question asked.